# NuGet missing .nuget folder i c:\Users\MyUserName

Tags: msbuild, nuget, portable-class-library, nuget-package-restore

I finally caved and installed VS2015 on my build server to avoid the pains of installing the necessary components individually, but now I'm presented with a new error when building.

Running MSBuild on my solution yields the following error:

```
 "C:\Users\Bamboo\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\IMP-COOK-JOB1\Imp.Cook.Api\Imp.Cook.Api.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Bamboo\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\IMP-COOK-JOB1\Imp.Cook.Api\Imp.Cook.Api\Imp.Cook.Api.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\Bamboo\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\IMP-COOK-JOB1\Imp.Cook.Api\Imp.Cook.Models\Imp.Cook.Models.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target) ->
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(89,5):
error : The package Microsoft.CSharp with version 4.0.0 could not be found in 
C:\Users\Bamboo\.nuget\packages. 
Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.
```

Now, I can manually create a .nuget folder in the Bamboo users dir, and that helps (it still fails on the next package `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`).

But what piece of the puzzle am I missing here? I run `nuget restore` before running msbuild, and it gets the packages I use directly in my project.

`Imp.Cook.Models` is a portable class library targeting Windows 10 Universal apps and .NET 4.6.

The build server is running Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had more or less the same issue as you so I can share my insights in how I got it to work. First off we have Bamboo running as a service (4 agents). It is important to note that the services needs to logon as a user and not the system account to be able to restore the packages (I do not yet know why). Given that you have a user map indicated as the source for the packages I'll assume that part is ok.

Next up you need to have a properly configured nuget.config file that you will use together with NuGet.exe. Mine looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Then you need to run the restore command using NuGet.exe (I suggest you get the latest Commandline version from [NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html%22NuGet%22)

I use the following command in a Bamboo step to restore the packages:

```
NuGet.exe restore "Path_To_Solution" -ConfigFile "path_To_ConfigFile" -NoCache
```

After that you should see the packages being downloaded to the C:\Users\Bamboo\.nuget\packages folder. When you try to build the solution in the next step using MsBuild it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question so late. I still have the problem from time to time, so I will definite give it a go!

Comment: I've just suffered through this entire process while developing a Xamarin app in the latest Visual Studio. I read contradictory things about whether a config file should be used or not. Including contradictory information in Microsoft's doc and on nuget.org! To make matters worse I had to also add third-party nuget repos *and* add nuget.org downloads that somehow don't show up within the Visual Studio package manager. Just *what* is the official, sanctioned approach here now?

Comment: The only way to properly restore packages using nuget.exe is by adding the config file. Otherwise, NuGet will get the config file from the locations it knows e.g. $ENV:APPDATA\NuGet\NuGet.Config in PowerShell.

This one is rather standard and does not hold all the sources, you can take a look at it yourself. So, in order to make sure NuGet can find everything we need, we add our own config file. There isn't really an 'official' approach, MS mostly assumes you will build using their platform.

Answer (score 1):

To install Microsoft.CSharp, run the following command in the Package Manager Console.

Then input:

`Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp -Version 4.0.0`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.0

Comment: Could you explain how that actually solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was also receiving an error message of the "C:\Users\username.nuget\packages" form. I was able to solve it by first deleting both the Users\username.nuget folder, and all of the folders in the solution's packages folder, and then restoring the nuget packages.